# How to make the pop-up box invisible or smaller when using class btn-link button?

Tags: html, button, glyphicons

I am using the following code for making a button that looks like the glyphicon:

```
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-link">
<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-triangle-top" style="font-size: 20px;">
</span>
</button>
```

When I click on the button, a box appears around the glyphicon (following image) which is not desirable to me. How can I make this box invisible or even make it smaller?

[image]

For example in stackoverflow, such a box does not exist when you click on vote-up (which you can do right away on this post ;) )
Please help. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set `box-shadow` and `outline` to none when focused.

```
.btn-link.btn:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks. Do you mean btn-link:focus? There are like 7 of them in the bootstrap.css. I added what you suggested to all of them. The blue box still pops but this time it disappears more instantly.

Comment: @Mike : sorry updated `.btn-link.btn:focus {
    box-shadow: none;
    outline: none;
}`

Comment: Thanks that worked. Can you also please tell me how can I change the color of the glyphicon when it's clicked?

Comment: @Mike you can use `:active` or `:focus` https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:active